# Data access architectures with Raven DB

Tags: c#, architecture, data-access-layer, ravendb

What data access architectures are available that I can use with Raven DB?

Basically, I want to separate persistence via interfaces, so I don't expose underline storage to the upper layers. I.e. I don't want my domain to see *IDocumentStore* or *IDocumentSession* which are from Raven DB.

I have implemented the generic repository pattern and that seems to work. However, I am not sure that is actually the correct approach. Maybe I shall go towards command-query segregation or something else?

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'm not really experienced with the Command Pattern. I saw that it was used in [Rob Ashton's excellent tutorial](http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/09/28/ravendb-image-gallery-project-i.aspx).

For myself, I'm going to try using the following :-

- Repository Pattern (as you've done)
- Dependency Injection with StructureMap
- Moq for mock testing
- Service layer for isolating business logic (not sure of the pattern here .. or even if this is a pattern.

So when i wish to get any data from RavenDB (the persistence source), i'll use Services, which will then call the appropriate repository. This way, i'm not exposing the repository to the Application nor is the repository very heavy or complex -> it's basically a FindAll / Save / Delete.

eg.

```
public SomeController(IUserService userService, ILoggingService loggingService)
{
    UserService = userService;
    LoggingService = loggingService;
}

public ActionMethod Index()
{
   // Find all active users, page 1 and 15 records.
    var users = UserService.FindWithIsActive(1, 15);         
    return View(new IndexViewModel(users));
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public UserService(IGenericReposistory<User> userRepository, 
                       ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        Repository = userRepository;
        LoggingService = loggingService;
    }

    public IEnumberable<User> FindWithIsActive(int page, int count)
    {
        // Note: Repository.Find() returns an IQueryable<User> in this case.
        //       Think of it as a SELECT * FROM User table, if it was an RDMBS.
        return Repository.Find() 
            .WithIsActive()
            .Skip(page)
            .Take(count)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

So that's a very simple and contrived example with no error/validation checking, try/catch, etc... .. and it's pseudo code .. but you can see how the services are *rich* while the repository is (suppose to be, for me at least) *simple* or *lighter*. And then I only expose any data via services.

That's what I do right now with `.NET` and `Entity Framework` and I'm literally hours away from giving this a go with `RavenDb` (WOOT!)

Comment: Great answer! I will wait another few days to see if anybody else has got different views. Personally, I use the same techs and approaches, so your answers appears to be the closest.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve by that?

You can't build an application which makes use of both an RDBMS and DocDB, not efficiently at least. You have to decide for yourself which database you are going to use, and then go all the way with it. If you decide to go with an RDMBS, you can use NHibernate for example, and then again - no need for any other abstraction layer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What I am trying to do is to be percipient ignorant this is why I want to use additional level of abstraction.

Comment: You mean you want to achieve persistence ignorance. This is exactly why I wrote my second paragraph. If you use a document DB, you can't efficiently allow the use of RDBMS - you are going to lose all the sweet spots a document DB has.

Comment: But I will be bound to the interfaces defined in RavenDB, and I don't want to have specific interfaces, is that possible?

Comment: Well, you do need sessions and data stores, don't you?

Comment: Nope, I don't want my domain to know that there are sessions and stores, in fact nothing persistence specific. I want my domain to be separated from storage through the interfaces with concrete implementation maybe via Raven DB and maybe other nosqldb.

Comment: @oleksii All of RavenDB infrastructure can be initialised in a central locaiton (Global.asax, etc). If you use a Repository pattern for abstracting away storage mechanism, you will still have to rewrite the same amount of code, so no difference there. Except, you  lose all the benefits of RavenDB-specific features.

Comment: @synhershko +1 I can see what you are saying, so I don't understand why your answer was downvoted.